# Completing messages right using FIFO-Queue in Azure Service Bus with Logic App

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

Hi i am currently working with an integration using FIFO structure in a queue, in Azure Servicebus.

I have some messages that are related to each other and they have to be processed in order.

They get send in through a API as XML and have an id in the xml per message, which tells what message is related to the other and i set this as a Session ID before sending the brokered message to the queue.

So after the fact that they are now in the queue i have my Logic app pick the messages up by "When a message gets received in queue (peek-lock)".

After that the message gets processed and then (here comes my problematic part...), i use "Complete message in Queue" to Complete the message.

In this Connector is enter the "Queue Name", "Lock Token", "Queue Type = Main" and "Session ID" of the peeked message.

Picture for reference:
[image]

The thing is i sometimes get these Errors:

> "message": "Failed to complete the message with the lock token '{GUID}'. The lock on the message has been lost.\r\nclientRequestId: {GUID}",
>
> "message": "No session available to complete the message with the lock
>   token '{GUID}'.\r\nclientRequestId: {GUID}",
>
> "message": "This messaging entity has already been closed, aborted, or
>   disposed.\r\nclientRequestId: {GUID}",

My question is:

There is another connector called "Close a Session in a queue".
(For the record i'm not doing this step right now.)

Do i have to close the sessaion aferwards or what am i doing wrong getting this message.

Also worth noting here is i only pick one message from the servicebus related to a specific session at a time.

Comment: How long does it take to process the message (before calling the complete action) ?

Comment: Usually under 3 seconds but sometimes rare times up to 2 minutes. Also i have set the lock token expire time to max, that is 5 minutes. Cant set it higher than that. @Thomas